# What are the purpose of comments with @ in Joomla PHP files?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-coding-standards

There are PHP comments similar to these:

```
/** 
 * @package    Joomla.Administrator 
 * 
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved. 
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt 
 */
```

The editor I use (Sublime Text) always highlights the string starting with **@**. So, I think that such string has some relevance. I think those strings are read for something. So it is not a simple comment.

Speaking of the example above, what do @package, @copyright and @license mean? Are they read by browsers, by *.htaccess*, for something?

Comment: this is not read by browsers or htaccess - it's [**phpDocumentor**](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html) syntax

Comment: In some PHP frameworks like Symfony, annotations can be used for example `@Route("/")` or `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity` and will be read by annotation readers.

Comment: You are right.  They have relevance.  See DocBlocks - Joomla! Coding Standards Manual at http://joomla.github.io/coding-standards/?coding-standards/chapters/docblocks.md

Comment: Updated URL from @NivF007 https://developer.joomla.org/coding-standards/docblocks.html